# Face alignment in video using python

Tags: python, opencv, alignment

I want to perform face aligment in a sequence of frames from video. I am using itraface face detector tracker which tracks points of interest in the face. Those points ca be found here:

[image]

What I want to is to rotate (using Python code). My question is if there is a way to calculate the rotate angle using the points from the eyes or the mouth (extreme right and left points of the eye or the mouth). How can I calculate that angle?

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590516/how-to-get-3d-coordinate-axes-of-head-pose-estimation-in-dlib-c/36591123#36591123) be helpful ?

Comment: Am trying to figure out what are the algorithmic steps that i need to follow.

Comment: Have you understood the answer? It has all the OpenCV method to calculate the orientation of your face in 3D space.

Comment: Yes but I guess there is a simpler solution to align the face in 2D case, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get both eye regions from your landmarks to compute the center of each eye. Then get the center point between the eyes. This is the point you want to rotate the face around.
Then use the coordinates of the both eyes to find the angle and build the rotation matrix with cv2.getRotationMatrix2D

You can find the details of this method [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/22/face-alignment-with-opencv-and-python/)

Comment: what if i find the angle between the two points and then rotate the whole image?

Comment: As long as you rotate it around the center point between the eyes.