# Head pose estimation based on 3d facial landmarks and a 3d model

Tags: algorithm, opencv, face

I have a 3-d face model and a detector that can get 68 3-d facial landmarks of an image. Does Opencv has API that can estimate the head pose estimation based on 3-d facial landmarks? I read its tutorials and found a function called cv2.solvePnP(). However, the input of this function is 2-d facial landmarks.

Comment: I don't want to convert 3-d facial landmarks to 2-d facial landmarks because I don't want to lose useful information.

Comment: No OpenCV doesn't has a direct API for calculating feature points in 3D space, But you may look at dlib C++ and also on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590516/how-to-get-3d-coordinate-axes-of-head-pose-estimation-in-dlib-c/36591123#36591123)