# opencv solvePnP coordinate systems

Tags: opencv

I am trying to use the `solvePnP` in the OpenCV calibration functionality to calibrate my camera.

So, the object in my case is a car and the origin is at the ground under the left tail light. The `x-axes` runs along from left to right and the `y-axes` is along the length of the car and the `z-axes` is along the height of the car. Now, the image coordinate system in OpenCV is at the upper left corner of the image and the pixel location is reported as `(y, x)` where `y` is along the rows and `x` is along the column. This is traditionally flipped from most image processing tools, I think.

My question is for the `solvePnP` function to work correctly, do I need to do something to image coordinates in terms of changing its origin or flipping the (row, cols) indexing or will this be somehow taken into account when estimating the calibration matrix. For me, it seems to be the latter but I could not convince myself that it is indeed the case.

Comment: You can use the coordinates as it is. You may want to consult this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36591123/3051961) for a demo

Comment: the opencv 3d camera model coordinate system ist: positive x to the right, positive y to the bottom, positive z away from the image (depth), afaik. There is a drawing somewhere in the docs websites.